# How do I guide users to use the Windows program necessary for my Android app?

Tags: android, windows-os

I have published a small Android App. It is a Remote Control for PowerPoint. The Software itself would work just fine, however I have a few small issues with my users. As you can imagine, a user has to install a small Windows Program. In order to control a Slideshow, a User must start the App and the Windows Program, and then they have to scan a QR Code. In between I am running a TomCat Servlet XMLRPC Container, where I get some usage Information from the HTTP Server Log.

I have a Website with Instructions and Downloads. Most Users I find in my Apache Log are only starting the App, they never pair with a SlideShow, and of course, they never come back.

To me it looks like, they found my App in Google Play, the install it, and then they notice that they need to install a program on a Windows Computer having also PowerPoint installed. I can't get rid of the Windows Tool, so I need to guide my users clearly to the download.

What is the best way to make sure my users are able to use the app and tool without getting frustrated or without realising that one part of the pair exists?

Comment: So presumably you already have the app when launched show something like "Searching for computers running Remote Receiver…"? Why not link them on that page to "Don't have it installed? You can download it for free from my-friendly-url.com".

Comment: Thats what I am doing right now. Except the suggested auto detection feature.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions on this.

First off, make sure it's displayed prominently in your Google Play listing that use of your app requires the installation of a paired Windows program.  With that you'll be able to let your potential users know before they even download the app.

Second, the first screen the user comes to (aside from a splash screen if necessary) should display the URL the user can visit to download your paired Windows program.  The URL should also be clickable if the user wants to download and store the paired app on their phone so they don't have to download it on every computer they go to.  The URL should also be easily retrieved from an about page of some sort so they don't have to remember it after seeing it the first time.

Lastly, make sure the URL is easy to type in on a computer.  Nobody wants to type in some long URL like `http://www.mywindowsapp.com/builds/january/20/2011/release/mypairedapp_v2.2.1.123.msi`
People would much rather type in a short vanity URL like `myapp.com/paired`.  Make the URL as short and pleasant as possible for your user to type in as to encourage them to take that step and download your Windows program.

Additionally you could prominently display your Windows program on your site and allow potential users to scan a QR code from your program that will open up Google Play on their phone for them to download your app.  That'll get people who are already sitting at their computer and have the pairing program engaged in your Android version.

Comment: First I thought, thats obvious, but then I nothiced that my Download Link is almost as bad as your example. And the QR Code on my Instruchtions Page is also a very good idea.

Comment: Based on that, I had the idea to add a Button "Send Download Link yourself", that Button will start the normal Mail Activity and the Link will be in the Boddy. A user only has to type in his own eMail Adress. I hope it is not to confusing.